# Spring MVC 3 i18n, how to store locale in session instead of URL parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm making a spring web app with i18n support. Right now the way the app works is that if there is a language defined in the URL parameter it'll use that, and if the parameter doesn't exist or is empty it will use the default. However I'm not satisfied with having the parameter there and I'm wondering if there's a way I can store the locale in session so it's behind the scenes and persists over all pages in the web app(because now if there is no locale parameter in the URL it'll use the defaultLocale).

My current configuration is:

applicationConfig.xml

```
<beans ... >
...
  <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="hr" />
  </bean>
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" >
      <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: Your setup should already do as you describe. The `SessionLocalResolver` stores the used locale in the session. The `LocaleChangeInterceptor` will change it to what the user wants and for that it requires a parameter, after that it should work without the parameter. If it isn't you have something wrong in your setup.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hmm... Alright then. Time for debugging I guess.

Comment: I would suggest moving the mvc configuration to the configuration loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` not the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by using  instead of  tags so I'll consider this question resolved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hi @MrPlow, you solved it by using what instead of tags?